# No maximum(minimum) of rationals whose square is lesser(greater) than $2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A$ is the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2 <2$ and $B$ is the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2 > 2$. We want to show that $A$ contains no largest element and $B$ contains no smallest element.

In Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, he associates $q = p- \frac{p^2-2}{p+2} = \frac{2p+2}{p+2}$. Did he just come up with this using trial and error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choice of $q$ in Baby Rudin's Example 1.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/choice-of-q-in-baby-rudins-example-1-1)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist this is a question asked in 2010! How can you mark it as a duplicate with a question asked in 2012?

Comment: @rtybase The age of the question is not relevant to the closure process (and closing as a duplicate is also not meant as a reprimand or punishment, it is only to help organization). See, for instance, this post on Mathematics Meta: [Original post marked as duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16417). This is also discussed on Meta SE: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643).

Comment: @rtybase Of course, in this specific case, one could argue that the answers here are better and can be prioritized over the answers on the duplicate link. I felt otherwise and hence flagged this question as a duplicate (and at least 5 other users happened to agree with me). If you, and other users, wish to reopen this question and close the other question as a duplicate of this one, that will also be fine with me. As I mentioned earlier, my interest is in helping in organising the posts on this site.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist have you seen the context? "Does this answer your question?" - no, because time machine was not invented ;) ... the topics you refer in the Meta are also old, from the time when duplicates were duplicates and not "Does this answer your question?"