# For integer $n>3$, prove that $n^2+(n+1)^2\ne (n+2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, quadratics

I have a number theory question:

> Consider any three consecutive natural numbers the smallest of which is greater than $3$. Then prove that square of largest cannot be the sum of squares of other two.

I took three natural numbers and tried to proceed with given conditions, but my approach is not working.

Please help.

Comment: Do you think this is applicable on $n<3$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $n,n+1,n+2$ be three consecutive natural numbers and $n>3$ (as required).

With given condition, let us assume that there exist three such consecutive natural numbers such that:

$(n+2)^2=n^2+(n+1)^2$

$\implies n^2+4n+4-(2n^2+2n+1)=0$

$\implies -n^2+2n+3=0$

$\implies -(n+1)(n-3)=0$.

Notice that the LHS cannot be zero as $n>3$.

A contradiction.

Comment: This is a good example of a proof by contradiction that really _isn’t_ one! Instead of making an assumption that there is a solution and showing it to be impossible, you can directly show that that quadratic equation has no solutions $> 3$.

Comment: @Lynn, there are various methods which a person can adopt. I respect your opinion but I often use proof by contradiction because I like them. I agree that there are various method and I will also upvote an answer having one, but for me this is okay. I would tend to give an answer which I like even if it cost me 2-3 lines more. Thanks for your words.

Comment: I'd love to try and convince you that "forced" proofs by contradiction like the above are generally a little less helpful than their corresponding direct proofs, but Qiaochu has already written what I wanted to write :) http://math.stackexchange.com/a/319926/259262

Comment: @PatrickStevens, I m glad to have your words and the link you provided. Thanks. You know what, you convinced me. I know that proof by contradiction are a little vague to establish, but as I explained in my previous comment, it is the way I do things. But now, from your and lynn's comment, I have changed my mind (not totally) and I shall keep it in my mind while writing proofs in future.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we have three numbers, $n, n+1, n+2$ where $n > 3$. Suppose that $(n+2)^2 = n^2 + (n+1)^2$ for contradiction. Then $$n^2 + 4n + 4 =  2n^2 + 2n + 1 \implies -n^2 + 2n +3 \implies n = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 4(3)}}{-2}$$So the only cases where the largest number squared is equal to the sum of squares of the two smaller numbers is when $n = -1, 3$, both of which preclude the assumption that $n>3$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $(n+2) \times (n+2)$ balls. Count balls at the boundary, in two ways:

[image]

The 4 sides contribute  $4 \times (n+1)$ balls as shown. On the other hand, the boundary is the total $ (n+2)^2$ minus the balls in the inner square $n^2$. Therefore, $(n+2)^2 - n^2 = 4 (n+1) \neq (n+1)^2$ unless $n = 3$.

Answer (score 4):

The single counterexample $16+25\ne36$ suffices.

Comment: Though the quantification in the OP is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that
$n^2+(n+1)^2 = (n+2)^2
$,
which is true for
$n = 3$.

Then,
if $k > 0$
and $n \ge 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
(n+k)^2+(n+1+k)^2-(n+2+k)^2
&=n^2+2nk+k^2+(n+1)^2+2k(n+1)+k^2\\
&\quad -((n+2)^2+2k(n+2)+k^2)\\
&=n^2+(n+1)^2-(n+2)^2+2nk+2k(n+1)\\
&\quad-2k(n+2)+k^2+k^2-k^2\\
&=2k(n+(n+1)-(n+2))+k^2\\
&=2k(n-1)+k^2\\
&> 0\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$(n+k)^2+(n+1+k)^2
>(n+2+k)^2
$.

Answer (score 3):

There's not so much space between consecutive squares!
$$(n+2)^2=(n+1+1)^2=(n+1)^2+2(n+1)+1<(n+1)^2+n^2$$
as soon as $2n+3<n^2$, i.e. $(n-1)^2>4$.

Answer (score 3):

$$(n+2)^2-n^2=
[(n+2)-n]\cdot[(n+2)+n]=
2(2n+2)=4(n+1)
$$

So if you want $4(n+1)=(n+1)^2$, you have either $n+1=0$ or $n+1=4$.