# Theorem cannot be proven directly

Tags: soft-question

Can we ever prove a theorem cannot be proven directly (i.e. We must use contrapositive or prove by contradiction.)? Can we even rigorously defined whether a proof is direct or not?

Example:
I was reading [Steiner–Lehmus_theorem: Every triangle with two angle bisectors of equal lengths is isosceles.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%E2%80%93Lehmus_theorem)

I knew a few elementary proofs of this theorem, but none of them are direct proof (for example: constructing congruent triangle).

The wiki page briefly mentioned the debate on whether equating algebraic expressions for angle bisectors and factoring is a direct proof or not, I don't quite understand that part either.

Comment: You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243770/can-every-proof-by-contradiction-also-be-shown-without-contradiction) for more details.