# Is there a strictly non-constructive proof for every constructive proof?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

An example of a **non-strictly** non-constructive proof: given a constructive proof of p, transform to a new proof of p via the lemma p & q where q is a fixed sentence that is classically but non constructively valid.
By **strictly** non-constructive proof I mean that you prove p without constructing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can every proof by contradiction also be shown without contradiction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243770/can-every-proof-by-contradiction-also-be-shown-without-contradiction)

Comment: No. I know there are proposition that can be proven in classical logic but non constructively, what I am asking is: if it’s known that p can be constructed, can I prove p without constructing it for every p? It’s almost the opposite question but without trivial answers

Comment: Not very clear... From a "classical" point of view a *constructive* proof is valid. Thus, every constructive proof is also classical. Having said that, we can trivially transform $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ into $\Gamma, \lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi$ and thus we have $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi$ that is **not** constructively valid, because uses DN.

Comment: but $ \Gamma, \lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi $ is still a constructive proof if you use $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ to prove it and the latter is constructive, right? In this case $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \lnot \varphi \vdash \varphi$ is not **strictly** non-constructive in the sense that I defined it before