# how to convert proof by contradiction to direct derivation?

Tags: logic

A statement is true if the denial of the consequent is inconsistent with the premises.If the statement is true there must exist a derivation for it.Inverting the semantic tableuax gives the inference rules,is there any other method which one can use?

Comment: You can form the contrapositive statement and then prove that one by contradiction. =)

Comment: thanks will look into it

Comment: @Michael While every proof by contraposition can be recast as a proof by contradiction, [the converse is not necessarily true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705291/21813).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243770/can-every-proof-by-contradiction-also-be-shown-without-contradiction