# Can we directly prove $\sqrt {2}$ is irrational?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Classic proof is that we assume $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then so on.

But can we prove it directly, not using proof by contradiction?

If yes, how? If not, then why?

Thank you!

Comment: You can have a look at : [Question on a constructive proof of irrationality of $\sqrt 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589603/question-on-a-constructive-proof-of-irrationality-of-sqrt-2)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with trying to prove such a thing directly is in the definition of an irrational number. We define an irrational number as some number that can't be written in the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are both integers. So to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not irrational, we have to prove that it cannot be written in such a form, which means we have to do a contradiction somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

By Eisenstein's criterion, $x^2-2$ is irreducible. Thus $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. You can prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is real using the mean value theorem.