# Logarithm proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-writing

Prove by contradiction that $\log_5 8$ is irrational.
While I understand that this is true, I am struggling to prove it by contradiction. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Now I wonder if there is a simple proof for statements like this that is not by contradiction ... [I no longer wonder this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/irrationality-proofs-not-by-contradiction)

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction, so suppose it *is* rational and that it can be written as $p/q$ (in its simplest form). But then:
$$\log_5 8 = \frac{p}{q} \Leftrightarrow 5^{\frac{p}{q}} = 8$$
Rewrite this as:
$$5^p = 8^q$$
**Hint**: what can you say about both sides being odd or even?

Comment: THis leads to a contradiction by even and odd and by Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\log_{5}8=p/q$

$$\log_{5}8=p/q$$

From $\log$ rules:

$$\iff 5^{p/q}=8$$

Power of $q$ for both sides:

$$\iff 5^{p}=8^q$$

The RHS is even and the LHS is odd and it is can't be

$\square$

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense!