# Density of rational numbers

Tags: general-topology

Let $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p^2<2$. Find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $p+\varepsilon\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $(p+\varepsilon)^2<2$.

I need the explicit form of $\varepsilon$. Can anyone show how to find $\varepsilon$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know any classical methods for getting approximate values for square roots?

Comment: $(p+\epsilon)^2-2=(p^2-2)+2p\epsilon+\epsilon^2$.

Comment: I wrote the expression in this form but what it gives? I can't understand

Comment: Take a look at, say, the Babylonian method for getting square roots:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots. (special case of Newton's method).  That gives you a good way to improve any estimate you have and it happens that if your estimate is rational, so is the better approximation produced by the method.  Warning:  on its own the method will give you a value greater than #\sqrt{2} but it is not difficult to get what you want out of it.

Comment: It's all great but I thought that explicit form of $\varepsilon$ can be found more simple. Maybe somebody know this.

Comment: @Pacman I'm pretty sure David is suggesting that you now use the quadratic formula, solve $$A\varepsilon ^2+B\varepsilon+C<0$$ where $A = 1$, $B = 2p$ and $C = p^2-2$. This will yield two solutions for $\varepsilon$, so take the one that is negative (if it exists)

Comment: Any choice of rational $\epsilon \in (0, \sqrt2-|p|)$ will work.

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/choice-of-q-in-baby-rudins-example-1-1)

Answer (score 3):

If $p<0$ then we can take $\varepsilon = -p >0$. So let's assume that $p\ge0$.

$(p + \varepsilon) ^ 2 = p^2 + 2p\varepsilon +\varepsilon^2$
and so it is enough to take $\varepsilon$ such that $p^2 + 2p\varepsilon +\varepsilon^2< 2$.

We shall look for $\varepsilon < 1$. Then $\varepsilon^2 < \varepsilon$ and so it is enough to take $\varepsilon$ such that $p^2 + 2p\varepsilon +\varepsilon\le 2$. The largest solution is
$$
\varepsilon = \frac{2-p^2}{2p+1}
$$
If $p$ is rational, then so is $\varepsilon$.
Moreover, $p^2 < 2$ implies $\varepsilon >0$.

However, this $\varepsilon$ may not satisfy $\varepsilon <1$.
So we take
$$
\varepsilon = \min\big(1,\frac{2-p^2}{2p+1}\big)
$$

Comment: How you got $\varepsilon=\dfrac{2-p^2}{2p+1}$?

Comment: Why the cases $p<0$ and $p\geqslant 0$ are so important? Where did you use them?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/choice-of-q-in-baby-rudins-example-1-1.

Comment: Dear lhf, why the cases $p<0$ and $p\geqslant 0$ are so important? I can't find this in source that you gave

Comment: @Pacman, they simplify the analysis.

Comment: Dear lhf. If $\varepsilon=\dfrac{2-p^2}{2p+1}$ then how to prove that $(p+\varepsilon)^2<2$. Your post is very hard for me and I can't understand some moments :(

Comment: @Pacman, the last value I gave is the one that works.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\epsilon = \frac{1}{\lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - \lvert p \rvert} \rceil + 1} \in \mathbb{Q}$$

Because

$$0 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - \lvert p \rvert} < \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - \lvert p \rvert} \rceil + 1$$

We have

$$0 <\epsilon < \sqrt{2} - \lvert p \rvert \leq \sqrt{2} - p $$
$$ -\sqrt{2} < p + \epsilon< \sqrt{2}$$
$$(p + \epsilon) ^ 2 < 2$$

Comment: $\sqrt{2}-\left|p\right| < \sqrt{2}-p$ should read $\sqrt{2}-\left|p\right| \le \sqrt{2}-p$.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: Except that to compute $\varepsilon$ with your formula, you need to know $\sqrt 2$...