# Prove that $(G, \circ)$ is group, $G=\{x, -1<x<1 \}$ and $x\circ y =(x+y)/(1+x*y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inequality

If $1<x, y< 1$ then $-1<x*y<1$ and $0<1+x*y <2$, but then I can't prove that 
$-1<x\circ y =(x+y)/(1+x*y)<1$. Help please.

Comment: I am not sure what you are not able to prove. The thing you have written is the definition, so there is nothing to prove there.

Comment: I can't prove that $-1< (x + y)/(1+x*y)<1$

Answer (score 4):

Knowing formula: $tanh(a + b) =\dfrac{tanh(a) + tanh(b)}{1 + tanh(a) . tanh(b)}$.

written under the form

$$a+b=tanh^{-1} \left(\dfrac{tanh(a) + tanh(b)}{1 + tanh(a) . tanh(b)}\right)$$

and setting $A=tanh(a)$ and $B=tanh(b)$, you get:

$$tanh^{-1}(A)+tanh^{-1}(B)=tanh^{-1}(A\circ B)$$

Thus you have proved that $((-1,1),\circ)$ is a group law by a mere transport of the additive law on $(\mathbb{R},+)$ by bijective function $tanh^{-1}$.

Have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group) which provides different "transport" examples, "$\circ$" operation being one of them.

Comment: See also section $6$ in Sam Northshield's [paper on Associativity of the Secant Method.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/15006/242)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Thnk you very much for this very interesting link.

Comment: You're quite welcome. And +1 for presenting a *conceptual* viewpoint. Btw, in English we often say [transport the (group) structure.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+transport+)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Thanks. Yes, I think that it is even one of our main roles as "seniors", to bring, wherever we can, this conceptual viewpoint. Besides,  I have made the correction transfer->tranport in the text  ; I appreciate your remark; being French speaking, it is sometimes tricky because although a good part of the abstract vacabulary is very similar in both languages, there are quite subtile differences...

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|<1,|y|<1$, to prove
$$
\left|\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right|<1\tag1
$$
Just prove $\:\:|x+y|<|1+xy|$. Square both side, we have
$$
x^2+y^2+2|xy|<1+2|xy|+x^2y^2
$$
Rearrage it we get
$$
(1-x^2)(1-y^2)>0
$$
This is true for $|x|<1,|y|<1$. So we conclude that $(1)$ be true.

To prove $(G, \circ)$ is group, note that $0$ is identity and $-x$ is inverse. I assume that you know how to prove for associativity and rest.