# Let $a \in R$ and let $a^n$ be right quasi-regular, where n is some positive integer. Show that $a$ is right quasi-regular

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I have tried the following way:
$(a^n◦x)=0$ so $(aaaa...a◦x)$ so $(aaaa...a)(a◦x)=0$ so $aaaa...a=0$ or $a◦x=0$ if $aaaa...a=0$ then $a=0$ and $(a◦x)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004269/let-r-be-a-ring-define-a-circle-composition-in-r-by-a-b-ab-ab-a-b/2004302#2004302), there is an isomorphism $\varphi:(R,\circ)\to (R,\cdot), \: \varphi(a)=1-a$. So $a^n$ is right quasi-regular iff $1-a^n$ is left unit, i.e. there $x\in R$ that $(1-a^n)x=1$. But there is
$$
(1-a^n)x=(1-a)(1+a+\cdots+a^{n-1})x=1
$$
Thus $1-a$ is also left unit and so $a$ is right quasi-regular.

Comment: Yes, thank you,
Is there another way to do that without using isomorphism?

Comment: I am not sure. It looks like your way is not working for $((ac)◦(xc))\neq c(a◦x)$