# Constructing a certain rational number (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis

I am not sure how this number is constructed.

[image]

I know that $2>q^2>p^2$, I then also know that q>p, hence I could construct a q such that q>p. I therefore choose q=p+x, where x could be an element of of rationals and then given I know that $2>q^2$ then $2>(p+x)^2$, so I should be able to solve for x. But since I cant use square root( have not created the real number line yet) I need to figure out how to solve $2>p^2+2 p x+x^2$

How would I proceed?

Or am I completely off track?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choice of $q$ in Baby Rudin's Example 1.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141774/choice-of-q-in-baby-rudins-example-1-1)