# How can compute the closest square to a given number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To be more accurate in what I'm looking for, I'm trying to express a number as a sum like
N= n²+r where N is the given number and n² is the closest square to it. 
An Interesting observation is that n² could be grater than N, which makes r be negative. For example, closest square to 63 would be not 49, but 64 so
$63 = 8² - 1 $
I know I can simply compute the square root in calculator but that's no the idea cause I'm planing using this to approximate square root of big numbers with secondary students. 
I was trying to use the fact that every square is $4k$ or $4k±1$
So I was trying to simply make a consecutive division by 4 for trying to express the number in the wished way but it don't always works
**EG**
$835 = 4(208)+3 = 4(196+12)+3=4 \cdot 14² +51=28²+51$
So, closest square, minor than 835, is $28²$
But, when I do the same with 5361 for eg
$53561 = 4(13390)+1 = 4(4(3347)+2)+1 = 4²\cdot 3347+9 = 4³\cdot 836+57 = 4⁴\cdot 209 + 57 = 4⁴ (14²+13)+57 = 224²+3385 $
Wich is the form but 224² clearly is no the closest square.
Maybe you can give a more optimal ideal, thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, n can be grater than N and that makes that r can be negative.

Comment: Then $29^2$ is closer to $835$.

Comment: @peterwhy You're right

Comment: @peterwhy the way I was working only takes minor values of N ... :(

Comment: $\lfloor \sqrt{N}+\frac{1}{2} \rfloor^2$, see [A053187](https://oeis.org/A053187)

Comment: The [digit-by-digit method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation) was taught in school  before there were calculators.  I used it in an exam when I forgot my slide rule.  If you have a calculator you can modify it to extract about half as many places at a time as you have digits in the calculator.

Comment: Newton's method and related iterative approximation schemes yield efficient algorithms, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141941/242) for an explanation of Rudin's approximation of square-roots via the *secant method*.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.  Let $f(N)$ be the number whose square is the closest to $N$.  Clearly $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.  Define a new function $g(N)$ by
$$
g(N) = f(N) - 2f(\left[N/4\right]),
$$
where $\left[N/4\right]$ is $N/4$ rounded to the nearest integer.  We might expect $g(N)$ to be small... checking directly, it is in fact the case that $|g(N)| \le 1$ for all $N$.  (It also has an interesting-looking form, rotating between increasingly long runs of $0$'s, $1$'s, and $-1$'s... but we don't need to find a closed form for this exercise.)  So a working recursive algorithm for $f(N)$, which takes $O(\log N)$ steps, is to first find $x=f([N/4])$, and then choose whichever of $\{x-1,x,x+1\}$ has its square closest to $N$.